# Is there cleaner way to define React Hooks useState on the top level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Wizard component that has a lot of state properties. It's used to hold the state of about 5 pages worth of content, then controls the submission to the api.

In the first example, I abide by the first rule of Using React
Hooks.

*1. Only Call Hooks at the Top Level*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Wizard = props => {
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState(props.uuid)
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [address1, setAddress1] = useState('')
    const [address2, setAddress2] = useState('')
    const [address3, setAddress3] = useState('')
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('')
    //etc for many  

    return (
        <div>
           {/*
           <Page1 firstName={firstName} secondName={secondName} />
               //...more pages 
           */}
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wizard uuid={123} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I think the component setup is a bit verbose so I wanted to put all the `useState` calls in a different function (to eventually move to a separate file) and for it to return `state` and `setters`.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const generateState = props => {
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState(props.uuid)
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [address1, setAddress1] = useState('')
    const [address2, setAddress2] = useState('')
    const [address3, setAddress3] = useState('')
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('')
    //etc for many  

    return {
        state: {
            firstName,
            //etc
        },
        setters: {
            setFirstName,
            //etc
        }
    }
}

const Wizard = props => {

    const {
        state,
        setters
    } = generateState(props)

    return (
        <div>
            {/*
            <Page1 firstName={state.firstName} secondName={state.secondName} />
                //...more pages 
            */}
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wizard uuid={123}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The second example breaks the first rule, which I guess is fine if "those are the rules!". **My question is, is there a cleaner way to define the `useState` calls at the top of a component and avoid the error:?**

```
React Hook "useState" is called in function "generateState" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Note: I want the state to be in the component, rather than else where (i.e. Redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useReducer` hook. Or just use plane state object like below.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  uuid: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  address1: '',
  address2: '',
  address3: '',
  addressState, ''
});
```

Comment: I used this method as it was cleaner... but discovered that to use this method to update one value, you have to send the previous state through also: setState(...state, ...newState)

Answer (score 2):

Lint error you are getting because you did not followed react guideline to create custom hook instead of naming `generateState` use `useGenerateState` linter error won't come.

What you are doing in second section is creating custom hooks that is correct only if you want it to be more cleaner the just use `useReducer` hook.

Check this refs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

That case code will be without linter errors:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const useGenerateState = props => {
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState(props.uuid)
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [address1, setAddress1] = useState('')
    const [address2, setAddress2] = useState('')
    const [address3, setAddress3] = useState('')
    const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('')
    //etc for many  

    return {
        state: {
            firstName,
            //etc
        },
        setters: {
            setFirstName,
            //etc
        }
    }
}

const Wizard = props => {

    const {
        state,
        setters
    } = useGenerateState(props)

    return (
        <div>
            {/*
            <Page1 firstName={state.firstName} secondName={state.secondName} />
                //...more pages 
            */}
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wizard uuid={123}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In situation like this yes, you can move it to separate hook but when I'm dealing with things like form etc what I do is use `object` within the state like.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  uuid: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  address1: '',
  address2: '',
  address3: '',
  addressState, ''
});
```

Using above approach the only way to set these individual values is as follow:

```
setFormData({ ...formData, lastName: value_of_last_name });
```

Using above approach the code stays clean and follow all the react hooks' rules.

Regarding the error you are getting is becuase of a React Hooks rule.

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.  more at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your are using eslint for error checking.

The reason why you are getting this error is that the way the write custom hook is inconsistent with the recommended way.
The offical reactjs says that the custom hook should return an array instead of a object. If you can change your custom hook to the following, the error should go away:

```
const generateState = props => {
const [uuid, setUuid] = useState(props.uuid)
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
const [address1, setAddress1] = useState('')
const [address2, setAddress2] = useState('')
const [address3, setAddress3] = useState('')
const [addressState, setAddressState] = useState('')
//etc for many  

return [uuid,setUuid,firstName,setFirstName,lastName,setLastName,address1,setAddress1,address2,setAddress2,address3,setAddress3,addressState,setAddressState]
```

}

whey you use your custom hook, use it like this:

```
   const [uuid,setUuid,firstName,setFirstName,lastName,setLastName,address1,setAddress1,address2,setAddress2,address3,setAddress3,addressState,setAddressState] = generateState(props)
```

Comment: No where react says custom hook should return array.